# Tooltip is not working when I am using CString

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am creating a tooltip for my controls in the Dialog as mentioned below .

```
    LPTOOLTIPTEXT lpTTT = (LPTOOLTIPTEXT)pNMHDR;
    CString csText;
    csText.Format("Yes !!! Tooltip cameToolTip testing");
    lpTTT->uFlags = TTF_DI_SETITEM;
    lpTTT->lpszText = csText.GetBuffer(csText.GetLength());
    lpTTT->hinst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
    return FALSE;
```

I used the above set of code in `OnTtnNeedText()` function and I called `EnableToolTip()` in `OnInitDialog()` function .

When I am hovering my controls I only see some small rectangle.
Please anyone help me out !!!

Comment: When do you think the content of the CString is going to be deallocated? You might get away with declaring the CString instance as static within the function, although you're not going to win a beauty-prize with that.

Comment: [How To Display More Than 80 Characters in a ToolTip Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180646). Money quote: "The buffer that you use must be a static, global, or dynamically-allocated buffer as long as it exists after returning from the notification. The buffer cannot be created on the stack because it will not be valid after returning from the message."